# ¿es posible poner la directiva ng-click dentro de un <span> o un <a>?

Tags: angularjs, html5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
     <span ng-if="contacto">Teléfono:  
         <a href="TEL://{{contacto.telefono}}">{{contacto.telefono}}</a>
         <m ng-if="contacto.extension"> Ext: 
             <a ng-repeat="ext in contacto.extension.split(';')" href="TEL://{{contacto.telefono+ext}}">{{ext}}</a>
         </m>
     </span>
```

y quiero poner un `ng-click` para avisar que se ha hecho click en el teléfono, pero no sé si es posible, ya que he intentado poner `ng-click` en la etiqueta `<a>` pero no me funciona.

en el contolador tengo lo siguiente...

```
     $scope.registrarllamada = function(c){
            console.log("Estamos llamando a.." + c.telefono);
    }
```

en la vista hice esto...

```
     <a ng-click="registrarllamada(contacto)" href="TEL://9{{contacto.telefono}}">{{contacto.telefono}}</a>
```

Pero no funciona, no me imprime nada al ahcer click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instrucción no es on-click, sino `ng-click`, probá el siguiente código:

```
<span ng-if="contacto">Teléfono:  
     <a ng-click="alert('Clickeaste en {{contacto.telefono}}')" href="TEL://{{contacto.telefono}}">{{contacto.telefono5}}</a>
     <m ng-if="contacto.extension"> Ext: 
         <a ng-repeat="ext in contacto.extension.split(';')" href="TEL://{{contacto.telefono+ext}}">{{ext}}</a>
     </m>
 </span>
```

Por cierto, fijate que pusiste {{contacto.telefono**5**}} Eso prodria traerte problemas si no es un tributo declarado

Comment: ya lo he probado y no funciona... si, se me fue el dedo al escribir por eso puse el 5 pero lo tengo correcto en mi código.

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("Ctrl_List", ["$scope", function(scope) {
  scope.registrarllamada = function(c){
            console.log("Estamos llamando a.." + c.telefono);
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <a ng-click="registrarllamada(contacto)" href="TEL://9{{contacto.telefono}}">{{contacto.telefono}}</a>
  <span ng-if="contacto">Teléfono:  
         <a href="TEL://{{contacto.telefono}}">{{contacto.telefono}}</a>
         <m ng-if="contacto.extension"> Ext: 
             <a ng-repeat="ext in contacto.extension.split(';')" href="TEL://{{contacto.telefono+ext}}">{{ext}}</a>
         </m>
     </span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

De hecho esta correcto lo que estaba haciendo, el problema que tenía es otro ya que uso ui-router y estaba asociando otro controlador a esa vista por lo que no encontraba el $scope.